# Facebook PHP SDK 3 won't work on 32-bit system, facebook ids treated as int and can be > 2147483647, best solution?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using facebooks PHP SDK version 3. It turns out that it won't work on 32-bit system as the SDK casts the facebook ids to integers and the ids can be larger than 2147483647 that is a 32-bit systems max integer value.

I also found the issue here https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/11

Is there anyone that has a "not so hacky" solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a workaround for this. Just change integer to string

Find this line

```
$user = $signed_request['user_id'];
```

and change it to

```
$user = (string) $signed_request['user_id'];
```

and also find

```
$user = $this->getUserFromAccessToken();
```

and change it to

```
$user = (string) $this->getUserFromAccessToken();
```

and also find

```
$user = $this->getPersistentData('user_id', $default = 0);
```

change it to

```
$user = (string) $this->getPersistentData('user_id', $default = 0);
```

And it works. Int isn't able to handle such a long user ids on 32bit systems, that's why is it making problems

Answer (score 1):

Until Facebook come up with a fix, I'd suggest you use one of the solutions in the comments.

Converting the number into a string is the only way to resolve your issue for these types of numbers on a 32 bit system.