# php variable in query - postgresql

Tags: php, facebook, string, postgresql

I have problem with query value.

This is working.

```
$userArray = $database->select("app", "fb_id=14175962160");
```

but below isn't working. Why?

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); // contains my fb id - 14175962160

$userArray = $database->select("app", "fb_id='$user'");
$userArray = $database->select("app", "fb_id=$user");
$userArray = $database->select("app", "fb_id=" . $user);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't working"? What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: Are you trying to run this on a 32bit server? You may be experiencing integer overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505203/facebook-php-sdk-3-wont-work-on-32-bit-system-facebook-ids-treated-as-int-and/6505347#6505347  Did you `var_dump($user)` to see what value it actually contains?

Comment: I don't believe, that $user = 14175962160, because in this case "fb_id=$user" string is the same as the working string.

Comment: ah the $user is int(1417596216) and should be int(14175962160). But I don't know why the zero is missing. (string) $user == string(10) "1417596216"

Comment: @VladimírVolek Try to print $facebook->getUser(); instead of saving it into the variable. What does it give?

Comment: print $facebook->getUser(); == 1417596216. Still wrong

Comment: @VladimírVolek Then, this function is giving you the wrong result. The question is: why.

Comment: Yes I know that already :) trying different facebook acoount now.

Comment: Just a side note: Please read http://bobby-tables.com/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, and http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php . Not an issue for integers, but in general string substitution into SQL is just a very bad habit; don't do it, *always* use parameterised statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was that I manually saved bad fb id to the database (With zero on the end) and I didn't notice that for a day. that's all :D. Thank you guys